# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'. >

Tags: android, kotlin

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
> Compilation error. See log for more details

I've tried several ways but still can't get it, is there any other suggestion to solve the error?